# value case in Ruby

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

How read value of variable in **case**?

```rb
effect = case x
when 1,2,3
  value.to_s
when 10
  "ten"
else
  raise "Trouble"
end
```

How I can read **x** value inside **when**

Comment: You can just use `x` directly.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `x` directly:

```
effect = case x
  when 1,2,3
    x.to_s
  when 10
    "ten"
  else
    raise "Trouble"
end
```

Comment: only `effect = x` ?

Comment: @MarkoLustro What do you mean?

Comment: @MarkoLustro Are you referring to the `efect` variable in the OP's question? Looking at the edit history, this appears to have been added after my original answer.